# Copy a variable of a function

Tags: ios8

In my code I have this function

```
 @IBAction func go(sender: AnyObject) {

    let Button = sender as UIButton
    name = Button.titleLabel!.text
    var label: UILabel = UILabel()
    label.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, 10, 150, 21);
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.text = "\(self.name)"
    self.view.addSubview(label)
    }
```

I want to copy label.text value in this Function

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "go" {
       }
 }
```

Comment: So, what's the problem with that?

Comment: nobody, I want only to copy the value of Label.text and then bring it into another function